# How do I find the answer to these basic log function questions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I know this is very basic stuff but I don't know how to find the answer to question (d) in this. The questions are about the log function (in base $10$):

$f(x)=3\log_{10}(10x+4)+2$

a) The largest domain of f is $x>a$ for some $a$, therefore what is the value of $a$?

b) What is $f(2.3)$?

c) What is $f(x)=8.2803$ for $x$?

d) Say $b$ is a number for which both $b$ and $1000b+1998/5$ are in the domain of $f(x)$. Find the simplest possible expression for $f(1000b+1998/5)−f(b)$.

For question (a) I calculated "a" to be $-0.4$.

For question (b) I calculated it to be $6.29409$ by formulating it as  $f(x)=3\log_{10}(10(2.3)+4)+2$ and following that through.

For question (c) I calculated it to be $12.0$ by formulating it as $8.2803=3\log10(10(x)+4)+2$ and solving for $x$.

I, however, don't know how to get the question (d).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: I can't add context by stating what I understand about the problem because I don't understand the question, hence why I have come here

Comment: "How do I answer these?": one at the time, in the same language they were written in and in the form of a short essay where every computation is introduced by a short exposition of what it stands for.

Comment: Let's start with a simpler question.  What the domain of $g(x) = \log_{10} x$?

Comment: @Haagexa Why are you people incapable of helping other people out on questions they are obviously stuck with by offering, either way, to solve it or solutions for it, rather you approach either dismissively or with an arrogant/superior air about, there is a reason that this place has a lot of negative stereotypes about it, again I cannot provide my working out for this because I don't understand it (shocking), if I did I would have provided it, but instead it ends up as a pointless catch 22 scenario, some actual help would be appreciated

Comment: @N.F.Taussig x>0 ?

Comment: That is correct.  Therefore, what must be true about $10x + 4$?  Note that adding $2$ does not affect the domain, nor does multiplying by $3$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig -0.4 right? Does that mean that the answer to a) is -0.4?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig wait so when trying to calculate questions (b) and (c) how do I format it? Do I format it (b) like $f(x)=3log_10(10(2.3)+4)+2 $ it gives me 6.29409, is this correct?

Comment: Your answers to parts (a) and (b) are both correct.  You should add your work to the question.  Also, add your attempt for part (c).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yeah I will in a minute, but for (c), is it the same process that I did for (B)? Would I enter the equation in as $f(x)=3log_{10}(10(8.2803)+4)+2$ or would I enter it in as "$8.2803=3log_{10}(10(x)+4)+2$ solve for x$ which gives me an answer of 12.0. Thank you by the way for helping me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The equation $8.2803 = 3\log_{10}(10x + 4) + 2$ is correct, as is your answer.  To get help with the last part of the question, type up your work for the first three parts of the question in the question itself.  Questions which do not show attempts are not well-received here.

Comment: Many reasons people don't answer (1) Nobody can mind read, they do not know your motivation, experience, what you don't know, if you are very lazy, if you just want an answer not an explanation and so on (2) People don't know if this is a test question, an exam question. Some cues help - did the person put in their own thoughts, show so effort, show some willingness to learn, ask for a hint rather than a full answer. Keeping all of this in mind, how would you rate your own question?

Comment: In part (a), you calculated $a$ to be $-0.4$, not the domain.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Edited it, but I still dont know how to get (d)? I tried what johnnyb said but that just makes me more confused????

Comment: I will not have time to answer your question for a few hours.  If it is not answered by the time I get home, I will address it then.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig All good, thankyou for helping

Answer (score 1):

(a) When a question asks about "domain", what they are asking is, "what are values for $x$ which produce a valid result?"  Think about the log function, and what values are valid for it.  Now, look at the expression that you are taking the log of, and think about which values of $x$ will give you values which are valid.

(b) This is a "plug and chug" question.  Just substitute that value for $x$ and see what you calculate as the result.

(c) This is confusingly written.  I'm going to assume it means if f(x) = 8.2803, then what is $x$.  For that, simply write the equation with 8.2803 in the place of $f(x)$, and manipulate it until $x$ is by itself.  To do this, when you want to "undo" the log function, remember that exponentiating is the opposite of the logarithm.

(d) For this, every time you see $f(\text{something})$, replace that with the contents of $f(x)$, but with every instance of $x$ replaced by the "something".  Then see how much you can simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

Your answers to the first three questions are correct.

We are given that $f(x) = 3\log_{10} (10x + 4) + 2$.  Hence, if $b$ is a number for which both $b$ and $1000b + \dfrac{1998}{5}$ are in the domain, then
\begin{align*}
f\left(1000b + \frac{1998}{5}\right) - f(b) & = 3\log_{10} \left(10\left(1000b + \frac{1998}{5}\right) + 4\right) + 2\\
&\qquad - \left[3\log_{10} (10b + 4) + 2)\right]\\
& = 3\log_{10} (10000b + 3396 + 4) + 2 - 3\log_{10} (10b + 4) - 2\\
& = 3\log_{10} (10000b + 4000) - 3\log_{10} (10b + 4)\\
& = \log_{10} (10000b + 4000)^3 - \log_{10} (10b + 4)^3\\
& = \log_{10} \frac{(10000b + 4000)^3}{(10b + 4)^3}\\
& = \log_{10} \left(\frac{10000b + 4000}{10b + 4}\right)^3\\
& = \log_{10} 1000^3
\end{align*}
where we have used the rules
\begin{align*}
\log_b u^n & = n\log_b u && \text{if $b, u > 0, b \neq 1$}\\
\log_b \left(\frac{u}{v}\right) & = \log_b u - \log_b v && \text{if $b, u, v > 0, b \neq 1$}\\
\frac{u^n}{v^n} & = \left(\frac{u}{v}\right)^n && \text{if $u, v > 0$}
\end{align*}
I will leave the final steps of the calculation to you.